# spring integration java dsl: how to expand a uri-variable in a Simp destination header

Tags: spring-integration

I use a mix of spring-mvc websocket support and spring-integration java dsl.

I have an integration flow responsible to send messages to websocket-stomp subscribers using AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.

The destination is /topic/notifications/{tenantId} where tenantId is a member of the payload I want to send to subscribers.

In spring-integration xml dsl uri-variable subElement.

I wonder if there is a similar java dsl feature I missed.

Currently I do something like:

```
.enrichHeaders( h -> h.< BizData > headerFunction(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.DESTINATION_HEADER , 
   m -> UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath( "/topic/notifications/{tenantId}" )
                            .build( false )
                            .expand(m.getPayload().getTenantId() )
                            .toString();
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are adding first class support for Spring Integration modules to the DSL as prioritized by users; we have not yet done websocket support. You can see which modules have first class support by looking at [the packages](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl).

That said, as you have found, not having **first class** support doesn't mean you can't use other modules in the DSL, it's just that some of the configuration is a bit more involved.

To help us prioritize the work, please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) indicating what you'd like to see. Even better, consider [contributing!!](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

However, for a simple use case like this, you might find a simple `String.replaceAll("...")` simpler than using the `UriComponentsBuilder`. I am not sure it's any more "elegant" but it's less code.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm still a noob at java-dsl but as soon as I get enough milage I'll definitively contribute. I like `UriComponentsBuilder` because it stays in "the family" and I'm already familiar with it, if it gets fixes or new features I'll be able to benefit from them.

Comment: No problem (re contributing); but at least open an 'improvement' JIRA issue, so we can track what people are asking for in the DSL.

Comment: I completely missed your reference to [websocket supports](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/web-sockets.html).Seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll take a look at it.